# AWS CDK Secrets Manger getting the full arn (python)

Tags: python, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to create a canary resource that uses a script that needs a secret.
I'm trying to add a policy statement to the canary role (which I'm creating as part of the cdk).
To do this I need to get the secrets full arn, I can get the partial arn with

```py
secret_from_name = secretsmanager.Secret.from_secret_name_v2
```

then use it like

```py
resources = [secret_from_name.secret_arn]
```

but that doesn't give me the full arn and the permissions don't work.

```
.....because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action
```

Thought I would get around this by doing

```py
resources = [secret_from_name.secret_full_arn]
```

But because this is derived by name, it doesn't get the full arn and you get 'undefined'

I also tried getting it from attribute using the partial arn, no joy there either.

So is there any way around this?  As what I don't want to do is pass around full arn's
or is there another way I can grant access to this reousece?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Secret ARNs have a dash and 6 random characters at the end.  Define the IAM policy statement's resource with a `-??????` [wildcard suffix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_examples.html#auth-and-access_examples_wildcard) to grant your role access to all versions of the secret name.

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<account-id-number>:secret:<secret-name>-??????"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In a CDK context you can simply use string concatenation to assemble the policy statement's resource ARN from the secret's name. Or use a CDK ARN utility ([Arn.format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk/Arn.html#arn) or [Stack.format_arn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk/Stack.html#aws_cdk.Stack.format_arn)).